# Heroku app crashed after pushing small change. Very confused

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am using Heroku with python and Flask. My app was working fine until I updated a few lines in my python application file. The app runs fine locally, but I now have the following error when I try to access my app:

*"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."*

My logs look something like this:

```
2012-10-03T17:40:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-10-03T17:40:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-10-03T17:51:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-10-03T17:51:26+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python presentation.py`
2012-10-03T17:51:26+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named site
```

I am also no longer able to run python through heroku:

```
Cinnas-MacBook-Pro:infinite-fortress-4866 cinna$ heroku run python
Running `python` attached to terminal... up, run.1
ImportError: No module named site
```

The next thing I have tried to do is check my environment variables:

```
Cinnas-MacBook-Pro:infinite-fortress-4866 cinna$ heroku config
=== infinite-fortress-4866 Config Vars
LANG:             en_US.UTF-8 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH:  /app/.heroku/vendor/lib
LIBRARY_PATH:     /app/.heroku/vendor/lib
PATH:             /app/.heroku/venv/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
PYTHONHASHSEED:   random
PYTHONHOME:       /app/.heroku/venv/
PYTHONPATH:       /app/
PYTHONUNBUFFERED: true
```

However, when I try to look inside the library directories, I get something like this:

```
Cinnas-MacBook-Pro:infinite-fortress-4866 cinna$ heroku run ls /app/.heroku/vendor/lib
Running `ls /app/.heroku/vendor/lib` attached to terminal... up, run.1
ls: cannot access /app/.heroku/vendor/lib: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure where to proceed at this moment. I miss my app, please help!

Additional information:

The problems all started when I added the following lines to my app.py code:

```
 @app.route('/my_fb_graph',methods=['GET','POST'])
 def my_fb_graph():
 return render_template('my_fb_graph.html')
```

When I pushed the code and the app no longer worked. I then removed these lines of code, pushed the code again, and still got the same errors. The next thing I did was to completely remove the app.py file and try to a small test code which still did not work.

The root of the problem seems to be the error:

```
 2012-10-03T17:51:26+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named site
```

Comment: You could start by describing exactly what the change you made was

Comment: if you change it back does it work again? if so there is likely a error in your change...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added some more information. I not only changed it back, I tried to remove the app.py completely and run a small test code.

Comment: @willglynn Yep, it is the Cedar Stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem, but still dont know why it occurred in the first place!

After a lot of experimentation, I ended up setting up a completely new app on Heroku. I checked the environment variables in the new app and got the following:

```
 Cinnas-MacBook-Pro:thawing-temple-4323 cinna$ heroku config
 === thawing-temple-4323 Config Vars
 FACEBOOK_APP_ID:  ***
 FACEBOOK_SECRET:  ***
 PATH:             bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
 PYTHONUNBUFFERED: true
```

Checking my original app (the broken one), I realized that new environment variables were somehow added in my last push as indicated by my logs:

```
 2012-10-04T04:20:04+00:00 heroku[api]: Add PYTHONUNBUFFERED, PYTHONPATH, PYTHONHOME, LANG, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATH, PYTHONHASHSEED, LIBRARY_PATH config by ***@***
```

and by checking my environment variables:

```
 Cinnas-MacBook-Pro:infinite-fortress-4866 cinna$ heroku config
 === infinite-fortress-4866 Config Vars
 LANG:             en_US.UTF-8 
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH:  /app/.heroku/vendor/lib
 LIBRARY_PATH:     /app/.heroku/vendor/lib
 PATH:             /app/.heroku/venv/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin   
 PYTHONHASHSEED:   random
 PYTHONHOME:       /app/.heroku/venv/
 PYTHONPATH:       /app/
 PYTHONUNBUFFERED: true
```

I removed these new variables with the command:

```
 heroku config:remove PYTHONPATH PYTHONHOME LANG LD_LIBRARY_PATH PYTHONHASHSEED LIBRARY_PATH
```

and my app started to work again. I've been pushing more code, and this problem has not occurred again.

I am still really curious why/how these variables were added in the first place since all I did was do a git push.

Comment: Thanks for this ! Side question: how did you get your logs ? The only command I known is 'heroku logs', is there any other ?

Comment: This worked for me as well, so thank you! I guess my app configuration is quite old?

Answer (score 5):

I experienced a very similar problem yesterday (6th Dec. 2012). Out of the blue, every python invocation died with 'ImportError: No module named site'. Heroku support got back to me today and they say it's fixed on their end, so the following workaround shouldn't be required. I'll leave this here in case it helps someone else diagnose.

I checked my heroku config vars though, and there were no PYTHON* variables set. They were set as env vars at the shell level though:

```
$ heroku run set | grep PYTHON
PYTHONHASHSEED=random
PYTHONHOME=/app/.heroku/venv/
PYTHONPATH=/app/
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true
```

/app/.heroku/venv was a non-existent directory. If I overrode PYTHONHOME with a config var, and pointed to where my virtualenv actually was, it all started working again:

```
$ heroku config:set PYTHONHOME=/app
```

/app appears to be a mount point for the project root directory. Digging through the history of the Python buildpack, it looks like when I started my project, everyone made their virtualenvs in the project root. Now new projects make virtualenvs in a venv/ subdirectory. Support said they were gradually rolling out a buildpack change, and I guess the checks for the old way of doing things didn't kick in for me.

Here's where to look for the buildpack internals:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/compile

Comment: Tried this...doesn't work. I'm using virtualenvwrapper...would that effect it?

Answer (score 2):

This bit me, too. I'm not sure when it started. I don't believe it was in response to any change on my part, I just noticed Application Error on my [site](http://aspen.io/) today, and found this in the logs:

```
2012-12-12T16:02:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-12-12T16:02:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `aspen --network_address=:40856 --www_root=doc/ --project_root=doc/.aspen`
2012-12-12T16:02:10+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named site
2012-12-12T16:02:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-12-12T16:02:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I had another release ready to go, so I just deployed as usual. After a `git push heroku`, the site is back up. My `heroku config` doesn't have the extra envvars listed above:

```
$ heroku config
=== aspen-io Config Vars
ASPEN_IO_SHOW_GA: yes
PATH:             bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PYTHONUNBUFFERED: true
```

**Update:** @kennethreitz [pointed me](https://twitter.com/kennethreitz/status/278894715712192512) to [this](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/wiki/Troubleshooting):

> **Cannot import module site**
>
> This occurs when the configured environment variables don't match the
>   paths of the installed Python. When this occurs, it is because someone
>   purged an app's cache without understanding the above implications.
>
> To fix, either purge the cache and update the configuration, or
>   restore the expected configurations (preferred).